# Topology Question

Tags: general-topology

**Let A, B and C be subsets of a topological space X with C⊂A ∪ B. If A, B and A ∪ B are given the relative topologies, prove that C is open with respect to A ∪ B if and only if C∩A is open with respect to A and C∩B is open with respect to B.**

I have proven already that if C is open with respect to A ∪ B, then C∩A is open with respect to A and C∩B is open with respect to B. What I have not been able to prove yet is that if C∩A is open with respect to A and C∩B is open with respect to B then C is open with respect to A ∪ B.

I have used the fact that since C∩A is open with respect to A, then C∩A=$G_1$∩A for some $G_1$ on Τ (the topology for X) and C∩B=$G_2$∩B for some $G_2$ on Τ.

I tried using  ***($G_1$∩A)∪ ($G_2$∩B)=C*** to see if I can spot which open set G on Τ will work so that G∩(A ∪ B)=C, but have not been lucky with that, and I have used De Morgan rules but still have not been convinced.

Thanks for any help

Comment: **If** this is true for $A,B$ then the sets have the so-called gluing property. If you have continuous functions $f:A\to Y$ and $g:B\to Y$ that coincide on $A\cap B$ then $h:A\cup B\to Y$ prescribed by $x\mapsto f(x)$ if $x\in A$ and $x\mapsto g(x)$ if $x\in B$ is a well-defined *continuous* function. Unfortunately you need extra conditions for this to be true. E.g. $A,B$ are both closed, or $A,B$ are both open.

Comment: Yes. I had taken this problem from a book, but it had no additional conditions for A nor for B. José already told me it is false and gave me an example of why it's false. Thank you drhab as well. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't prove it, because it is false.

Take $X=\mathbb R$, with the usual topology, $A=C=(-\infty,0]$ and $B=(0,+\infty)$. Then $C\cap A$ is open in $A$, $C\cap B$ is open in $B$, but $C\cap(A\cup B)$ is *not* open in $A\cup B$.

Comment: Than you so much. I had spotted this problem on Schaum's Outline for general topology chapter 5, and I thought about it for such a long time yesterday but was getting nowhere. Now that I see why, I may continue on my journey.